# Quick CakePHP method question

Tags: php, cakephp

I have seen this is some CakePHP methods `function view ( $id = null )` but what does it mean?

e.g. what is the difference between:

`function view ( $id = null )` and `function view ( $id )`

Also how would I enforce so that the view method expects an id so for example `domain.com/Controller/View/someothertext` would cause an error 404 as its not an ID

Answer (score 0):

The `view` function takes a single parameter (`$id`). If none is supplied, a default value of `null` will be used.

If you wish to changve the default value, you can change it like this:

```
function view ( $id = 'domain.com/Controller/View/someothertext' )
```

Comment: Link to documentation about this - [Default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). Also, when `$arg = null` is used with [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), it allows `null` to be passed as an argument, i.e., `function foo(array $bar) { }` cannot be called as `foo(null)`, while `function foo(array $bar = null) { }` does accept `null` as argument and therefore can be called as `foo(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: URLs Should always be lower case if you're going to follow CakePHP conventions.

If you have a function in one of your controllers, its parameters are determined by the URL

For example:
`domain.com/users/view/foo/bar/`

Would call:

`UsersController::view('foo', 'bar');`

In your case, the view function would take the ID of the user, so if you wanted to call the view function for the user with ID 12, you would set the URL to: `domain.com/users/view/12`

The default value is there to prevent PHP errors in the case that the URL doesn't contain parameters, ie: `domain.com/users/view` would call `UsersController::view();`. Because the default value is `null`, it would be just the same as calling `UsersController::view(null);`

As for your second question:

Your view function could be like this

```
function view($id = null) {
   if (!is_numeric($id)) {
      $this->redirect('/404.html');
   }
}
```

Comment: All methods are Capitalized in CakePHP 2.0 hence the urls being like that

Comment: Are you sure about that? CakePHP 2.0 changes the filenaming structure. So instead of having `users_controller.php`, you would use `UsersController.php`. I don't think anything is changed in the URL conventions. It doesn't make sense for them to do something that quirky with URLs. I've never seen camel-cased URLs in ANY type of framework or website structure and don't really ever expect to.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does and they're not camel cased but capitalized

Comment: Ok, thanks. You're still talking about CakePHP, right? I think we're straying off topic a little. Did I answer your question or are you still confused?

Comment: You need to come up with the logic to determine if $id is a valid ID, and put it in your controller's view function. I put an example at the bottom of my answer